# responsive and equal height for a set of boxes

Tags: jquery, css, html

[image]

There are three boxes in a line, each one containing an image and a title.
I can use `height` property to make their height equal. But in a Responsive view, when the boxes shrink, because of the fixed height, a box will look with an extra white space after the title (specially when the title fill just a line, not two)

I can use `padding-bottom`, but it will not give my boxes an equal height, because some have a longer title and will fill two line instead of one, so will have more height.

What's the solution of giving these boxes an equal height which don't make me extra white space when shrink in responsive view?

Comment: Make a fiddle  for your problem...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G4PvQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use jquery add this code to the bottom of your page:

```
var max=0;
$('article').each( function (){
    if($(this).height()>max)
        max=$(this).height();
});
$('article').height(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

use overflow:hidden and height for your boxes (parent of the text containing element):

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:150px;">
```

Edit:
 http://jsfiddle.net/G4PvQ/2/

Comment: pesar khale use height + overflow hidden;) this should do the trick

Comment: You made No changes to the fiddle (it looks you didn't saved what you did). I didn't feel anything by adding overflow:hidden to the boxes.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. I edited the answer and of course the link

Comment: well, either text must be small or the overflow should be hidden for making them the same size. if you are using jquery I can give you much better answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40256/discussion-between-farzad-bayan-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani)

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem change `height` property with `min-height` which makes your box auto-resizable and add `padding-bottom` for increasing the bottom white space as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This problem of yours is a unversal problem which can be solved by CSS only solutions, but you should choose carefuly the solution you need.

Chris Coyier has published a great article on equal height fluid width items with 4 different CSS methods, which I personally like the FlexBox Method if you don’t care about the browser support.

**Article**: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/
**Demo**: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns/

Have Fun.